# Why jndi-lookup is not creating a EntityManagerFactory bean definition from JNDI?

Tags: jpa-2.0, weblogic-10.x, spring-data-jpa, persistence.xml, toplink

I created my app as J2EE app in JDeveloper 11g. It uses JSF 2.1, Spring-core 3.2.1 and Spring-data-jpa-1.4.4 among others Spring necesary modules. I've created a datasource in the integrated WebLogic server within the default domain. When I try to run the app the following error is showing up.

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:538)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:159)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

My WEB-INF/web.xml has the configuration to setting up the JSF servlet and Spring listeners:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>*.jsf;*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then there is the WEB-INF/faces-config.xml with the Spring integration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">  
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Then there is WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml with the Spring config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.*"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.myapp.repositories" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="MYJNDI"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

Then I created the persistence file under META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>MYJNDI</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.eclipse.persistence.example.jpa.server.business.Cell</class>
        <class>org.eclipse.persistence.example.jpa.server.business.CellAttribute</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic 10"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Entity and Repository classes looks like this:

```
... imports
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTRIBUYENTE")
public class ContribuyenteEntity implements Serializable {

    @SuppressWarnings("compatibility:-6161811794505268140")
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7000366567373058605L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID_CONTRB")
    private Long idContrb;

    ... get and set methods
}

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Repository
public interface ContribuyenteRepository extends CrudRepository<ContribuyenteEntity, Long>{

}
```

I've performed the extra configuration on the server as the Oracle docs indicates:
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/tlandwls.htm#BABEDCEI

I don't really found out why the `<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="MYJNDI"/>` is not registering the EntityManagerFactory bean within the context. I'd really appreciate any help you can provide. Regards!